# C++ STL Containers. Parametrize a comparer for each different instance

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, predicate

I have a set of *n* objects representing coordinates in a map, and I want for each one of them to mantain a **priority_queue** with the *k* closest to their position.

Problem is **priority_queue** receives a class for a predicate instead of a function object so I haven't found a way to specify a diferent *point of reference* for every **priority_queue**

i.e something like:

```
std::priority_queue<
  Vertex*, 
  std::vector<Vertex*>, 
  DistanceComparer(fromVertex)> 
  pqueue; // doesn't compile
```

as opposed to:

```
DistanceComparer::from = fromVertex;
std::priority_queue<
  TRVertex*, 
  std::vector<TRVertex*>, 
  DistanceComparer> 
  pqueue; // compiles but unhelpful
```

Making *from* static really doesn't help since I need a different *point reference* for every **priority_queue**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::priority_queue` has constructor overloads taking an istance of the comparator class. So you just have to design your comparator as stateful (which you seem to have done already), and construct the priority queue accordingly:

```
struct Vertex
{
  std::priority_queue<Vertex*, std::vector<Vertex*>, DistanceComparer> pqueue;
  explicit Vertex(fromVertex *v) : pqueue(v) {}
};
```

Comment: That was easy. I guess I could have searched better. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the class as the template parameter, and an object of the class as an argument to the constructor, thusly:

```
std::priority_queue<
    TRVertex*, 
    std::vector<TRVertex*>, 
    DistanceComparer> 
  pqueue(DistanceComparer(fromVertex));
```